# Gensim/word2vec error: embedding layer error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, gensim, word2vec

I've been trying to implement an embedding layer using gensim's word2vec. I have loaded my data using pandas, my data is text type, when it comes to the word2vec part:

```
embedding_weights = train_word2vec(y_train, vocab['w2idx'], 
num_features=embedding_dim, min_word_count=min_word_count, context=context)
input_shape = (sequence_length,)
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
layer = Embedding(len(vocab['idx2w']), embedding_dim,
input_length=sequence_length, name="embedding")(model_input)
layer = Dropout(dropout_prob[0])(layer)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
   File "<ipython-input-9-423d0e432e5b>", line 3, in <module>
   min_word_count=min_word_count, context=context)

   File "C:\Users\ACER\Pod_Dsgn_Chatbot\Wor2vec.py", line 43, in 
   train_word2vec
   for key, word in vocabulary_inv.items()}

   File "C:\Users\ACER\Pod_Dsgn_Chatbot\Wor2vec.py", line 43, in <dictcomp>
   for key, word in vocabulary_inv.items()}

   File "C:\Users\ACER\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site- 
   packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1398, in new_func1
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

   File "C:\Users\ACER\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site- 
    packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 821, in __getitem__
     return self.wv.__getitem__(words)
   File "C:\Users\ACER\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site- 
   packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 171, in __getitem__
   return vstack([self.get_vector(entity) for entity in entities])

   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

i have no idea how to fix it, and there isn't much information on the internet, also the error  is related to the first line of the shown code. Finally note that i cleaned my data, and i removed every integer, thank you

Edit: And this is the function where the problem happens, Ps: i didn't develop this one

```
def train_word2vec(sentence_matrix, vocabulary_inv,
               num_features=300, min_word_count=1, context=10):

model_dir = 'models'
model_name = "{:d}features_{:d}minwords_{:d}context".format(num_features, 
 min_word_count, context)
model_name = join(model_dir, model_name)
if exists(model_name):
    embedding_model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load(model_name)
    print('Load existing Word2Vec model \'%s\'' % split(model_name)[-1])
else:

    num_workers = 2   
    downsampling = 1e-3   


    print('Training Word2Vec model...')
    sentences = [[vocabulary_inv[w] for w in s] for s in sentence_matrix]
    embedding_model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, workers=num_workers,
    size=num_features, min_count=min_word_count, window=context, 
    sample=downsampling)
    embedding_model.init_sims(replace=True)
    if not exists(model_dir):
        os.mkdir(model_dir)
    print('Saving Word2Vec model \'%s\'' % split(model_name)[-1])
    embedding_model.save(model_name)
    pyplot.scatter( embedding_model)
    embedding_weights = {key: embedding_model[word] if word in 
     embedding_model 
    else
                          np.random.uniform(-0.25, 0.25, 
      embedding_model.vector_size)
                     for key, word in vocabulary_inv.items()}
   return embedding_weights
```

Comment: The error is being triggered inside a function, `train_word2vec()`, whose code (in a file `Wor2vec.py`) you're not showing here. Show that code to give answerers a better chance of understanding what's going wrong. (You could also trim the triggering code down to something minimal – none of the stuff after that line is relevant to the error that happens early.)

Comment: Ok, i'll add the function so you can have a look at it.

Comment: The error is being triggered by the line with `vocabulary_inv[w]` in it, which means the type/contents of that parameter, passed-in as `vocab['w2idx']`, is crucial. Can you show what `vocab` is - either how it's constructed, or some hints of its type/structure/contents? Also, what is parameter `vocabulary_inv` *supposed* to be? (Does this `train_word2vec()` function you-didn't-write come with any docs? Where does it come from?)